# why logout doesn't work? Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I am clicking my logout button which is supposed to log me out. I did everything according to documentary but still I receive the following error

```
Unable to find the controller for path "/logout". The route is wrongly configured.
```

Here is my security.yml

```
firewalls:
  main:
    anonymous: ~
  dev:
    pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
    security: false
  secured_area:
    pattern:    ^/
    form_login:
        login_path:  /login
        check_path:  /login_check
        default_target_path: /
    logout:
        path:   /logout
        target: /
        invalidate_session: false
```

And I of course added

```
logout:
    path: /logout
```

to the routing.yml

What is wrong with my logout?

Comment: Where should I add it? Under logout in security.yml? I receive the following error then Unrecognized option "logout" under "security.firewalls.secured_area.logout"

Answer (score 0):

Adding such function solved the problem:

```
/**
 * @Route("/logout", name="logout")
 */
public function logingOut() {
    $this->get('security.token_storage')->setToken(null);
    $this->get('request')->getSession()->invalidate();

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('index_page'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you add the logout route in your files routing? try this in your console, and you should see the next:

```
app/console debug:router
...
  login                      ANY    ANY    ANY  /login
  login_check                ANY    ANY    ANY  /login_check
  logout                     ANY    ANY    ANY  /logout
...
```

if you can't see this, maybe you does not added the path in routing correctly.